# QT:как получить доступ с функции в mainwindow.cpp к переменим в main.cpp

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Собственно вопрос в заголовке. Есть функция, которая исполняется при нажатии на кнопку. Как получить доступ к переменим которые в main.cpp?

Comment: Сделать переменные глобальными или передать их по ссылке объекту класса MainWindow

Answer (score 0):

Первый вопрос - а оно вам точно надо?

и ответ на вопрос - напрямую никак, но вы можете передать параметры из main.cpp при инициализации MainWindow. Вот маленький пример: 
main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QApplication a(argc, argv);   
        QString param = QString(argv[0]); // пусть и бессмысленно, но будем передавать имя запускаемой программы.

        MainWindow w(param); // Инициализация (создание) MainWindow (см. конструктор MainWindow)
        w.show();

        return a.exec();
    }
```

MainWindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMessageBox>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QString p, QWidget *parent = 0); // в нонструкторе добавился доп. параметр 
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QString p, QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QMessageBox::information(this,"",p); // в реализации конструктора мы получили переменную из main.cpp и можем использовать на свое усмотрение
    this->show();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду думать

Comment: А можно добраться к значению формы из main.cpp?

Comment: принципиально то всё можно, но зачем все эти извращения? всё же можно делать непосредственно в mainwindow. зачем что-то туда-сюда гонять?